# Determing tag close with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document that I loop over and parse the output to console. All working etc, but I need to be able to determine where the tag closes from the parent Node. For example:

```
<activity date="2013-07-05T06:42:35" name="open" host="55.555.20.5554">
  <user id="EU-user@email.co.uk" name="J Bloggs" memberType="E" />
  <storageObject docId="4130-7447-0000" name="Documents name" size="1903885" fileExtension="pdf">
    <cabinet name="Client Cabinet">NG-XXXXXX</cabinet>
    <Matter>0000</Matter>
    <Client>X54654</Client>
    <Author>L Bloggs</Author>
  </storageObject>
</activity>
```

At the end of each activity, I would like to be able to output a line to determine on the console output where each activity ends.

Is there a way to determine when the element "close" tag occurs using XDocument?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you parsing xml or searching for closing tags? XDocument should be used for parsing

Comment: I'm parsing the XML. The contents of every element and attribute are written to the console. What I'm trying to do is detect where each `</activty>` tag occurs so that I can determine which activities are which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to determine where tag closes. XDocument will determine it for you:

```
var activities = from a in xdoc.Descendants("activity")
                 let u = a.Element("user")
                 let so = a.Element("storageObject")
                 select new {
                     Date = (DateTime)a.Attribute("date"),
                     Name = (string)a.Attribute("name"),
                     User = new {
                          Id = (string)u.Attribute("id"),
                          Name = (string)u.Attribute("name")
                     },
                     Storage = new {
                          Client = (string)so.Element("Client")
                     }
                     //...
                 };
```

It creates strongly-typed objects which you can iterate over:

```
foreach(var activity in activities)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", activity.Name, activity.Date);
```

Comment: If one of the attributes or elements happened to be null, would this affect the way XDocument handled it?

Comment: @JordanMoffat that depends on whether attribute has type which accepts null as value. E.g. for string it's OK, thus if there is no `name` attribute, you will have `null` value for Name. For `DateTime` you will have exception. So, use nullable DateTime instead: `(DateTime?)a.Attribute("date")`

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it only displays the top level attributes, and I can't seem to find a way to get it to detect the child nodes

Comment: @JordanMoffat what do you mean by top level attributes? Each element in xml has only one level of attributes

Comment: I mean top level in a tree sense. ie, it can't find the child elements attributes like `id` and it can't find the `client` or `matter` elements

Comment: @JordanMoffat why it can't find? It can. Attributes of `user` element are not part of `activity` element. If you want to get attributes of user, you should get user element. I've updated sample with inner nodes parsing

Comment: This is what I was meaning essentially. I figured that I'd have to specify various levels, but I couldn't find a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
// Load document into XDocument instance.
var doc = XDocument.Load("source.txt");

// query for all <activity> element.
var activities = doc.Root.Elements("activity");
// add XComment after each of them.
foreach (var a in activities)
{
    a.AddAfterSelf(new XComment("------------"));
}

// Print document into console.
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

It prints `<!--- - - - - - - - - - - - -->` after every `</activity>`.